# Glass issue, trasparent vs holdout shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, noise-reduction

I have a problem with the transparency shader.
I need to use it combined with the glossy one, mixing using a fresnel factor.
Unfortunately I keep getting the same result...an annoying black area.
ON the other hand, with Holdout shader everything seems to work correctly.
I'm attaching 4 screenshots that I hope will explain better the issue.

[image]

I've already seen a discussion about this theme:

"How to render semi-transparent objects with transparent background as a png with cycles"

but it's two years old and I don't know if something has changed in the meantime.

And all this, because I need to resolve an issue that I have in a scene.
I have a big surface made of glass, that is in front of all, this surface affects to much the render time and the level of noise.

[image]

Is there some sort of trick to resolve that problem?
I have already  play with light path, but nothing seems to work.
I think that the noise is caused by the refraction properties of the glass shader.
Can someone help me?

Thank you